# calling stored procedure from hibernate not working on performance scale

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, stored-procedures

I have a below stored procedure call from hibernate. Based on input, I have to delete data from DB (from multiple tables)

```
currentSession().createSQLQuery("CALL stored_proc_name(:param)").setParameter("param", "Sample");
```

Same is working fine on functional load, but when I'm executing same flow for performance data (having ~100k rows to be deleted via stored procedure), nothing is happening. Is this because Hibernate session is getting closed? Any pointers?

Comment: did you solve it? I'm having the exact same issue

Comment: `CallableStatement function = DAO.i().getHibernateUtil().currentSession().connection().prepareCall("{? = call some_stored_proc(?, ?) }");`  `function.registerOutParameter(1, Types.BOOLEAN);`  `function.setString(2, colName);`  `function.setString(3, colValue);`  `function.execute();`  I was able to solve it using above code.